# How fast is to get a Azure config value?

Tags: c#, azure, configurationmanager, azure-sdk-.net

Does it make sense to optimize Azure config settings calls?

Is there any numbers or implementation details that shows performance of `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting`?

Is it always a search in the configuration file? Or those settings are cached in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Caching is up to you. `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` first looks in ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file, if the key/value pair isn't found there, it will do a lookup in web.config appSettings.  Since web.config and ServiceConfiguration.cscfg changes require/force an application restart, the best practice is to get these values from a class with static members/properties.

Comment: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting will first look in to azure portal's config setting. so if you have any sticky setting there, it will get that then ServiceConfiguration.cscfg and then web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I think unless you are specifically experiencing performance issues that you think relate to configuration settings, or are pulling a very large amount of data from config files / environment variables, you are almost certainly going to get more of a performance boost by focusing your attention elsewhere in your application.

Ultimately this is reading data from a very small flatfile, or pulling it from memory (in the case of environment variables) If you're reading from it a lot, the OS will take care of disk cache. It seems very unlikely that you are going to make any improvements by doing something that would be considerably more complex to the OS than reading from a simple file.

Obviously, the only way you can be really sure is to create a testing strategy and get the figures out for yourself, with regards to how your solution is interacting with those things.

But I would be exceptionally surprised if you had any meaningful improvement from any other method.